# How to show a np polynomial in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy, tkinter

I'm new to Python and I was wondering if anyone knew an effective way to display a poly1d polynomial in a string (to be put in `tkinter.Label`), since I can't add a `numpy.lib.polynomial.poly1d` object in a string and therefore in the text of a label.

I've tried converting the `numpy.lib` object to an array, and then to a string, but it displays back only the coefficients.

Any ideas would be appreciated, have a great night!

Here's a mini version of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

root=Tk()

p= np.poly1d([1, 2, 3])
parray=np.array(p)
pchain=np.array2string(parray)

printpoly=Label(root, text="Result: %s"%(pchain))
printpoly.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="EW", rowspan=2, columnspan=1)

root.mainloop()
```

It doesn't work because it only shows the coefficients without exponents or x variables.

Comment: If it's the string you think it is, I don't see why it can't be displayed on a Label.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: The thing is that it only displays the coefficients, and I'm looking to display the whole polynomial.

Comment: If that's _not_ what string is, then this is the wrong question.

Comment: Is `"Result: %s"% np.poly1d(parray)` what you're looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert poly1d to string ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119255/convert-poly1d-to-string-ipython)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like:

```
printpoly=Label(root, text="Result:\t{}\n\t\t{}".format(
                        str(p).splitlines()[0], str(p).splitlines()[1]))
```

entire example:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
import numpy as np


def display_polynomial(poly1d_obj, label):
    def separate_lines():
        p_lines = str(poly1d_obj).splitlines()
        return p_lines


    sup_line, peer_line = separate_lines()
    label['text'] = "Result:\t{}\n\t\t{}".format(sup_line, peer_line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    p = np.poly1d([1, 2, 3])
    printpoly = tk.Label(root)
    display_polynomial(p, printpoly)
    printpoly.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```